# @RequestParam annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

My question may seem to be curious, because I'm newbie in Java.

I've read the oracle [lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html) about annotation in `Java`. But I have not understood yet how they work on practice. Consider the following `spring framework 4.0.1` defined annotation:

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequestParam {

    public String value() default "";

    public boolean required() default true;

    public String defaultValue() default "\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\ue000\ue001\ue002\n\t\t\t\t\n";
}
```

The annotation may apply to a function parameter like the following

```
 public void change(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("cost") String cost, @RequestParam("name") String name, Model model) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
         //id will have the value of param id, passing inside request
         //but ***I have no explicitly assignation*** requested parameter 
         //to the function parameter
    }
```

Who exactly assign requested parameter value to a corresponding function parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default (`@EnabledWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />`) MVC stack in the Spring version you are using uses implementations of [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to resolve arguments to use when invoking the handler method (method annotated with `@RequestMapping`).

For `@RequestParam`, that implementation is [`RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html).

The arguments are all collected, then Spring uses reflection to invoke your handler method. It passes the collected arguments during the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

The default **@EnabledWebMvc** or **< mvc:annotation-driven />** MVC stack in the Spring version you are using uses implementations of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve arguments to use when invoking the handler method (method annotated with `@RequestMapping`).

For `@RequestParam`, that implementation is `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`.

The arguments are all collected, then Spring uses reflection to invoke your handler method. It passes the collected arguments during the invocation.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring MVC you have to apply ;

```
1- index.jsp in WEB-INF
2- property names for index.jsp in view.xml
3- Controller for property names
4- mapping for controller in servlet.xml
```

If you want use @RequestParam in a project you need ;

```
-Form action in jsp
-Class for variables
-Controller for form variables.
```

Comment: Not clear. I thought, It is not necessary to have a firm action in jsp. Controller's action may be fo bussiness logic only.

Comment: Yes. It is just an example. You can set your class variables and i think You can use with @requestParam